# Spring Boot Multiple Datasource Set up

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am new with springboot i need to setup multiple database in my project i am using postgresql this is my properties file.

If i am running my application so whatever @primay annotation i am giving only that db i able to access but i need to access both db.

Note : if i am adding both db @primary annotation then getting postconstructor 0 something error. my query in if else block sometimes i need to access abc db and sometimes i need to access xyz db but whatever in springconfig i m keeping @primary only that db url i am getting

I tried making @primary both getting exception and i tried @configurationProperties adding in my springconfig file getting exception

```
spring.datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://100.17.13.26:123/abc
spring.datasource1.username=ENC(vAIVaqTTZ89eYBWBDbUxgGdhciXm3GuB)
spring.datasource1.password=ENC(abZypzjEuvLfbovYs0oGdeRnUqM8e+k1)
spring.datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://100.17.13.26:123/xyz
spring.datasource2.username=ENC(vAIVaqTTZ89eYBWBDbUxgGdhciXm3GuB)
spring.datasource2.password=ENC(abZypzjEuvLfbovYs0oGdeRnUqM8e+k1)
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

i add in @springBootApplication   SpringConfig class

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    
    @Bean(name = "abc")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        System.out.println("from first DB");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource1.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource1.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource1.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource1.password"));
        System.out.println("from first DB end");
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "xyz")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        System.out.println("from second DB");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource2.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource2.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource2.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource2.password"));
        System.out.println("from second DB end");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "abc")
    public JdbcTemplate template(@Qualifier("abc") DataSource ds) {
        System.out.println("calling first db");
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Bean(name = "xyz")
    public JdbcTemplate template1(@Qualifier("xyz") DataSource ds) {
        System.out.println("calling second db");
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use @Qualifier while accessing second non primary db.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc") 
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: thanks for reply i used that also still i am getting @primary db url not second one

Answer (score 0):

The JdbcTemplate beans should **NOT** have the same names as the DataSource Beans.

This simple example **DOES NOT** boot:

```
// In Config.java
@Configuration
class Config{
  @Bean("a")
  public String a() {
    return "a";
  }

  @Bean("b")
  public String b() {
    return "b";
  }

  @Bean("a")
  public Integer c(@Qualifier("a") String a) {
    return a.length();
  }

  @Bean("b")
  public Integer d(@Qualifier("b") String b) {
    return b.length();
  }
}

// In Comp.java
@Component
public static class Comp {
  private final String s;
  private final Integer i;

  public Comp(@Qualifier("a") String s, @Qualifier("b") Integer i) {

    this.s = s;
    this.i = i;
  }

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void ok() {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

**Because your config is the same as the above, it will NOT boot either!**

**HOW TO FIX IT:**

In the above example, if you change the names "a" and "b" on the `Integer` beans to "c" and "d", and change the qualifier value in the `Comp` constructor accordingly, it works fine.

p.s. I don't recommend ever using the `Environment` bean to grab your config values; personally I use `@Value("${the.key}")` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am using same i put code for SpringConfiguration class here.

Comment: Please re-read the answer carefully, and if my suggestion still does not work, then modify the original question _so that names are not being shared by different beans_

Comment: If it helped you, then you should upvote and accept the answer.